# html to json using javascript / nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

so I have a lot of dynamic HTML content (see example below), and I want to turn this raw HTML into a json string. The strings are different and over 40,000 lines, I want the most efficent way, was thinking a Node.JS based conversion tool for it.

Example of string data:

```
<div class="row convRow font-sans side-other" id="message_{RANDOM_STRING}" data-usertypeid="{user type id - random string}"><div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 conv-Image"><div class="hidden-xs"><a href="/@{PROFILE LINK - USERNAME}"><div class="userImage img-circle" style="background-image:url('{PROFILE PICTURE}');"></div></a></div></div><div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11 conv-Message"><img src="{BORDER}" class="bubbleTab"><div class="well" style="padding:7px"><div class="conv-Text" style="overflow:hidden">how is everyone? {THE MESSAGE SENT}</div><div class="conv-Time row"><div class="col-md-6"><a href="/@{PROFILE URL - USERNAME}/" data-usercard="PoeticPrince"><span class="userScreenName">@{USERNAME}</span> (M)</a> - {TIME} <span class="badgeHolder"></span> <span style="cursor:pointer" class="heartCommentButton compassionHeartFade" onclick="heartMsg({STRING - RANDOM});"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span class="pointHolder"></span></span></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="pull-right-md">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btn btn-xxs" onclick="referUserPopup({USER ID},{USERNAME});" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Troll">refer</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btn btn-xxs" onclick="muteUserPopup({USER ID}, {USERNAME});" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Hide messages from {USERNAME}.">mute/report</span></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

What's the best way to parse mass amounts of this data into JSON string?

Comment: `JSON.stringify( htmlString)`  will "convert raw HTML into a json string". Is the some reason not to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Have  a look at this library:

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/himalaya**

Sample code on how to use it:

```
var himalaya = require('himalaya');
var html = require('fs').readFileSync('/webpage.html');
var json = himalaya.parse(html);
console.dir(json, {colors: true, depth: null});
```

It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: good, but doesn't go deep enough. only goes one level:   { tagName: 'div',
    attributes: 
     { className: [Object],
       id: 'message_NrnM5P072BO5DeeppqEZr6ldlJjVAakW',
       dataset: [Object] },
    children: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    type: 'Element' } ]

Comment: @ssdev Are you sure it only goes one level? It doesn't appear to do so from their example. Try this line, after you obtain the json object ``console.dir(json, {colors: true, depth: null})`` to see the whole json object